# How to prevent deleting items in KendoUI multiselect?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-multiselect

I use a Kendo.UI MultiSelect in MVC

```
                @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
                            .Name("ADGroups")
                            .DataTextField("Name")
                            .DataValueField("Value")
                            .MinLength(3)
                            .Value(Model.SelectedADGroups)
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:auto", id="ADGroupsList" })
                            .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                            .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("GetADGroups", "Edit"))
                            .ServerFiltering(true))
                            .Events(e => e.Change("onChange").DataBound("onDataBound"))
                             )
```

And now I would like to prevent from deleting some Items.
So I save the current values on DataBound-Event

```
    function saveCurrent(multi)
{
    multi._savedValues = multi.value().slice(0);
    multi._savedItems = multi._dataItems.slice(0);
}

function onDataBound()
{
    saveCurrent(this);
}
```

And OnChange I detect the difference between before and after.

```
 function onChange()
{      
    var previous = this._savedValues;
    var current = this.value();
    if (current.length < previous.length)
    {
        var diff = $(previous).not(current).get(0);

            if (confirm('Sure?'))
            {
                // do nothing value already deleted
            }
            else
            {
                // reset
                this.value(previous);
            }

    }
    saveCurrent(this);
}
```

This works perfectly. But If I type a new phrase so the widget calls the Read-Action to add some Items all works fine and NOW when I delete an item and cancel this action, however items will be removed.
What is wrong?

Comment: Here is an existing example but without prevention.
http://jsbin.com/cowiyivitu/2/edit

Comment: Documentation from Telerik. There ist no OnDelete or OnRemove-Event.
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect
After setting this.value(previous) - this.value() does not contain the Array from previous. :-(